# Pandas count null values in a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
               'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
               'C' : [np.nan, 'bla2', np.nan, 'bla3', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

Output:

```
     A      B     C
0  foo    one   NaN
1  bar    one  bla2
2  foo    two   NaN
3  bar  three  bla3
4  foo    two   NaN
5  bar    two   NaN
6  foo    one   NaN
7  foo  three   NaN
```

I would like to use groupby in order to count the number of NaN's for the different combinations of foo.

Expected Output (EDIT):

```
     A      B     C    D
0  foo    one   NaN    2
1  bar    one  bla2    0
2  foo    two   NaN    2
3  bar  three  bla3    0
4  foo    two   NaN    2
5  bar    two   NaN    1
6  foo    one   NaN    2
7  foo  three   NaN    1
```

Currently I am trying this:

```
df['count']=df.groupby(['A'])['B'].isnull().transform('sum')
```

But this is not working...

Thank You

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `sum` of `NaN` values:

```
df2 = df.C.isnull().groupby([df['A'],df['B']]).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='count')
print(df2)
     A      B  count
0  bar    one      0
1  bar  three      0
2  bar    two      1
3  foo    one      2
4  foo  three      1
5  foo    two      2
```

Notice that the `.isnull()` is on the original Dataframe column, not on the `groupby()`-object. The `groupby()` does not have `.isnull()` but if it would have it, it would be expected to give the same result as with `.isnull()` on the original DataFrame.

If need filter first add [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['A'] == 'foo']
df2 = df.C.isnull().groupby([df['A'],df['B']]).sum().astype(int)
print(df2)
A    B    
foo  one      2
     three    1
     two      2
```

Or simpler:

```
df = df[df['A'] == 'foo']
df2 = df['B'].value_counts()
print(df2)
one      2
two      2
three    1
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

EDIT: Solution is very similar, only add [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['D'] = df.C.isnull().groupby([df['A'],df['B']]).transform('sum').astype(int)
print(df)
     A      B     C  D
0  foo    one   NaN  2
1  bar    one  bla2  0
2  foo    two   NaN  2
3  bar  three  bla3  0
4  foo    two   NaN  2
5  bar    two   NaN  1
6  foo    one   NaN  2
7  foo  three   NaN  1
```

Similar solution:

```
df['D'] = df.C.isnull()
df['D'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['D'].transform('sum').astype(int)
print(df)
     A      B     C  D
0  foo    one   NaN  2
1  bar    one  bla2  0
2  foo    two   NaN  2
3  bar  three  bla3  0
4  foo    two   NaN  2
5  bar    two   NaN  1
6  foo    one   NaN  2
7  foo  three   NaN  1
```

Comment: That answered my initial question perfectly, but I just realized that I had the 'Expected answer' wrong. Sorry About that. I need the result to be added to the initial dataframe.

Comment: The `name` argument in `.reset_index(name='count')` doesn't seem to be supported: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Answer (score 36):

```
df[df.A == 'foo'].groupby('b').agg({'C': lambda x: x.isnull().sum()})
```

returns:

```
=>        C
B       
one    2
three  1
two    2
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution in pandas to my taste. Btw in R data.table it would be only     `df[A=='foo', sum(is.na(C)), b]`

Answer (score 3):

just add this parameter dropna=False

df.groupby(['A', 'B','C'], dropna=False).size()

check the documentation:
dropnabool, default True
If True, and if group keys contain NA values, NA values together with row/column will be dropped. If False, NA values will also be treated as the key in groups.

Comment: This behavior is what I was looking for - basically something consistent with R's table(..., useNA = 'ifany')